# Pandas rolling calculation based on a mask condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
     A   B   C   D
0   58   3  25  94
1   54   4  99  85
2   87  98  74  36
3   63  68  79  51
4   25   7  42  12
..  ..  ..  ..  ..
95  50  19  90  99
96  68   1  52  98
97  96   2  98  21
98  90  25   5  23
99  56  93  48  19
```

I want to recompute those values that meet a certain criterium. There can be many criteria but for the sake of simplicity, let's just take a simple one: if a cell value is below 10% of the dataframe mean:

```
>>> mask = df<0.1*df.mean().mean()
        A      B      C      D
0   False   True  False  False
1   False   True  False  False
2   False  False  False  False
3   False  False  False  False
4   False  False  False  False
..    ...    ...    ...    ...
95  False  False  False  False
96  False   True  False  False
97  False   True  False  False
98  False  False   True  False
99  False  False  False  False
```

For each cell that meets this condition, I want to create a rolling window of size 10, compute the mean over that rolling window, and replace the cell's value with that mean. For all the rest of the cells in the original `df` dataframe, original values should be kept. Therefore we can think of this intuitively as: if we see a value that is too low, let's replace it by the average of the last 10 (in fact only 9, due to the way rolling window is defined in pandas) values.

Now I am a bit how to move forward from here. `df[mask]` will show me the cells that meet the condition but I am unable to apply a `.rolling()` on it since `df[mask]` has `NaN`s in all other cells that do not meet the condition.

Note that I prefer high performance as in reality both the criteria and the rolling window calculation will be more complicated, and the dataframe is much larger. Therefore I could do a simple for loop type of lookup but that doesn't suit my needs for this use case.

Comment: Which dataframe needs to be consider while calculating the rolling mean `df` or `df[mask]`?

Comment: The original dataframe without the missing values, i.e. `df` needs to be considered. `mask` is only defining the condition for the cells where the rolling window calculation needs to take place. For all the rest, the original values need to be preserved. Thank you for the great question, I'll update my post right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly:

```py
mask = df < 0.1 * df.mean().mean()
df[mask] = df.rolling(10, 0).mean()[mask]
```

Comment: Even more brief and elegant than what I came up with just now. Thanks a lot, @Pierre D!

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you want to treat NaN, but one approach is simply: df[mask].fillna(0).rolling(10).mean()

Comment: You're entirely right since I might have failed to explain myself properly. In fact, I only want to recompute values using the mean for cells that meet the condition described above. All the other cell values in `df`, i.e. the original dataframe should be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by turning the problem around: instead of focusing on figuring out how to *only* perform the rolling window calculation for those cells that meet the criterium, I first calculated the rolling mean for the entire dataframe:

```
>>> means = df.rolling(10).mean()
       A     B     C     D
0    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
..   ...   ...   ...   ...
95  46.3  35.2  44.8  41.5
96  46.1  40.0  42.0  48.0
97  49.6  45.6  42.8  52.6
98  46.7  39.5  40.3  49.9
99  43.6  42.5  35.9  46.7
```

Then, I simply took `df[mask]` where `mask = df<0.1*df.mean()*mean()` and assigned `means` to it like so:

```
df[mask] = means
```

This keeps the original `df` cell values where `mask` is `False` but will replace them with the corresponding cell values from `means` if `mask` is `True`.